# Odds of winning multiple raffles?

Tags: combinatorics

My work is having a raffle for 1000 dollars. The prize all goes to first place. There is an argument about what format is better for the players.

Some people want to do one raffle with 100 tixkets for $10 a ticket.

While other people want to do several raffles to decide.
 One main raffle with 10 tickets for 100 dollats a ticket and then do 10 other raffles with 10 tickets each at 10 dollars a ticket to get into the the main raffle.

Finally there is a group that wants to have one main raffle with 10 tickets costing 100 dollars a piece. They want to have 10 raffles at 10 dollars a ticket to get into that raffle as well but they also want to have Ten raffles with 100 tickets for 1 dollar a ticket to decide the winner of the 1000 dollars.

Which format gives an individual the best chance of winning if they only want to spend $10?